# Copying application url from one tab to another tab causing 404 error

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker

I have an application with back end in spring boot and font end with angular and I am using micro services.I have docarize each of the services and it was running without any issue.The problem I am facing when I copied the application URL when running as docker-compose up after login and pasted it in another tab in the browser ,I am getting 404 error.But in local when I did the same thing it was not happened . After copying the URL in local to other tab redirected me to the login page.
I am not able to figure out the issue and looking for some kind of lead.

Here is the Angular docker file:

```
# base image
FROM node:10.16.0-alpine AS build-step
# set working directory
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx:1.16.1-alpine
COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html/
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.5
    network_mode: host
    container_name: mysql-container
    ports:
      - 3306:3306  
    environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
     MYSQL_DATABASE: Test
     MYSQL_USER: root
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.6
    network_mode: host
    container_name: mongo-container
    ports:
      - 27017:27017 
  eurekaservice:
    image:  service1: eurekaservice
    container_name: eureka-container
    build: netflix-eureka-naming-server/ 
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8761:8761      
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
  zuulservice:
    image:  service2: zuuluservice
    container_name: zuuluservice-container
    build: netflix-zuul-api-gateway-server/
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - 8765:8765
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    hostname: rabbit
    container_name: rabbitmq-container
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672 
  accountmanagerservice:
    image: serviceAuth: accountmanagerservice
    build: accountmanager/
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    container_name: accountmanagerservice-container
    ports: 
      - 9200:9200
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - eurekaservice 
  bookmarkservice:
    image: servicebookmark: bookmarkservice
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    container_name: bookmarkservice-container 
    ports:
      - 6078:6078
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - eurekaservice
      - rabbitmq 
  recommendationservice:
    image: servicerecommended:recommendationservice
    build: recommendersystem/
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    container_name: recommendationService-container
    ports:
      - 6082:6082
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - eurekaservice
      - rabbitmq
  appui:
    image:  appuiservice: appui
    container_name: angular-container
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is your `angular/nginx` container. `nginx` is looking for a dashboard filename. The default `nginx` configuration in docker does not point urls that are not static (css/js) to your single `index.html`.

Add this conf file to your `nginx` container

```
worker_processes 1;
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    sendfile on;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_min_length   500;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_types        text/plain text/xml text/css
                      text/comma-separated-values
                      text/javascript
                      application/x-javascript
                      application/atom+xml;

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        index index.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; // any non static goes here
        }

        location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
            # Some basic cache-control for static files to be sent to the browser
            expires max;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        }

    }
}
```

In your `dockerfile` under your first copy add this line

`COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Comment: I have one doubt. Actually I have not manually installed nginx in my machine. I have dockarize it. So how could I add nginx.conf file as it was dockerized.

Comment: @stumbler add this line `COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to your `dockerfile` and place the `nginx.conf` in your home angular directory. This will add the `nginx.conf` to your nginx container. You are porting your localhost to your docker host `80:80` so no need for any nginx local install

Comment: What is happening is once you load your localhost angular is redirecting using angular router to the dashboard url. Which is fine until you reload. Your nginx docker container does not know that all requests (except for css/js) need to go to the angular `index.html` file. You need to setup the nginx docker container to point all requests to the index.html file that are not static. `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` This line looks to see if the file is static and if so returns the file (css,js) and if not point to the index.html file. Angular will know which route to point to

Comment: Thanks for the answer  @Varcorb. I will check and let you know .

Comment: I have added nginx.conf files in the home directory of my angular aps and also add COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and then dockarize the angular application. When I ran my docker compose I am getting the below error in the log:2019/11/22 04:21:59 [emerg] 1#1: unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:33
nginx: [emerg] unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:33
2019/11/22 04:22:29 [emerg] 1#1: unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:33
nginx: [emerg] unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:33

Comment: I checked in nginx.conf file and find that curely braces are closed correctly. Any idea do you have.

Comment: Are you able to manually build the image without docker compose? I did a from scratch test with this `nginx.conf` and everything worked for me. The only difference I did is I used the `nginx:latest` in lieu of the `alpine` image

Comment: yes, I can able to build the docker image. Ok let me try with nginx:latest then.

Comment: I copy and paste the same nginx.conf files which you have shared.But still I am getting the same exception when I manually run the angular container.